# Checking the JSON file information without using a temp table in T-SQL

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql

Let's say I have a JSON input parameter called `@ImageURL` in my procedure with the following structure which is used for storing and manipulating my Uploader section.

```
    [
        {
          "Title": "some title",
          "Urls": "some url",
          "Type": "application/pdf",
          "IsPrimary": true
        },
        ...
    ]
```

This JSON string always has more than one set of Title, URLs and etc. but there are some cases in which I insist to check that it contains only one since I can't be sure if front-end developers will send the JSON for me in a right format.
For checking this, I have used the following code which seems to be working but I feel like it's unclean and there might be a better way to write this than creating a TMP table and checking it's `COUNT`.

```
    DECLARE @JSONImageFile TABLE(
        Level1ID INT,
        JSONImageFile NVARCHAR(MAX),
        JSONImageFileTitle NVARCHAR(1000),
        JSONImageFileType NVARCHAR(100),
        JSONImageFileIsPrimary BIT
    )
    
    INSERT INTO @JSONImageFile(
        Level1ID,
        JSONImageFile,
        JSONImageFileTitle,
        JSONImageFileType,
        JSONImageFileIsPrimary
    )
    SELECT
        @Level1ID,
        Urls,
        Title,
        Type,
        IsPrimary
    FROM OPENJSON(@ImageURL) WITH (
        Urls        NVARCHAR(MAX),
        Title       NVARCHAR(1000),
        Type        NVARCHAR(100),
        IsPrimary   BIT
    )

    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @JSONImageFile) = 1 /* the main code */
```

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: `IF JSON_QUERY(@ImageUrl, '$[1]') IS NOT NULL`... This simply checks if a second element exists.

Comment: @JeroenMostert thanks for your answer this worked well for my json sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of a JSON array, you may try to parse this array with `OPENSJON()` and default schema and check the max value of the returned `key` column:

JSON:

```
DECLARE @ImageUrl nvarchar(max) = 
N'[
        {
          "Title": "some title",
          "Urls": "some url",
          "Type": "application/pdf",
          "IsPrimary": true
        },
        {
          "Title": "some title",
          "Urls": "some url",
          "Type": "application/pdf",
          "IsPrimary": true
        }
]'
```

Statement:

```
IF EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 
   FROM OPENJSON(@ImageUrl) 
   HAVING MAX(CONVERT(int, [key])) = 0
) 
   PRINT 'Success'
ELSE 
   PRINT 'Error'
```

Comment: Sorry for answering late. this solution worked well for my sample thank you very much. however someone in comments mentioned using `IF JSON_QUERY(@ImageUrl, '$[1]') IS NULL` which seems to be working well too. what's your take on this method?

Comment: @MateenBagheri, JeroenMostert explained it clearly _...This simply checks if a second element exists ..._. These two examples of possible JSON arrays may help you understand the deifference between this answer and the solution from the comment: 1) Empty JSON array: `[]`  2) JSON array with `NULL` second item: `[{"Title": "some title", ...}, null, {"Title": "some title", ...}]`. For both arrays `JSON_QUERY(@ImageUrl, '$[1]')` returns `NULL`, but the arrays do not have only one item. Thanks.